# EF add restriction for related entinies count

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design, architecture

I have an `Account`, `Product` and `Order` tables.

How to briefly describe that `Account` can't have more that 100 `Orders`, and more than 1000 `Products`?

It would be better to describe this behavior somehow in the `OnModelCreating`, or in the `AddProduct` and `AddOrder` methods, requesting it's count and restrict there?

**NB**: The question is related to `Entity Framework 6`.

Comment: Where are you recording the *rest* of your specification?

Comment: @philipxy in `onModelCreating`, but I'm not sure this could be implemented there.